# Mensaje de error si ingresas números negativos en sucesión de Fibonacci

Tags: java, bucle-for, fibonacci

Estoy intentando hacer un método con la sucesión de Fibonacci y todo bien. Mi problema viene cuando intento que el programa advierta de que no se puede realizar la sucesión con números negativos. Les dejo el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Dime hasta qué número quieres la sucesión de Fibonacci");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    int [] secuenciaFibonacciMain = fibonacci(num);
    
    if(secuenciaFibonacciMain.length>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < secuenciaFibonacciMain.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(secuenciaFibonacciMain[i]);
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("No se puede realizar la secuencia de fibonacci con el " +num);
    }
    
    sc.close();
    

}

public static int [] fibonacci(int num) {
    
    int [] fibonacci = new int [num];
    
    int num2Anterior=0;
    int numAnterior=1;
    int numeroFinal=0;
    if(num<0) {
        return new int [0];
    }
    if(num>=0) {
        fibonacci[0]=0;
        fibonacci[1]=1;
        for(int i=2;i<num;i++) {
            numeroFinal=num2Anterior+numAnterior;
            num2Anterior=numAnterior;
            numAnterior=numeroFinal;
            fibonacci[i]=numeroFinal;
        }
        
    }
    
    return fibonacci;
}
```

Si es menor que 0, le paso un array de 0 y ya luego en el main compruebo, pero me salta el siguiente error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -4

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ser?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: El array lo creas antes de comprobar que num sea negativo.

Comment: Pero me daría igual, ¿no? Ya que estaría declarándolo después de comprobar si el num es negativo o positivo, por lo que esa variable quedaría declarada únicamente dentro de ese if y no podría retornarla

Comment: El array `fibonacci` lo **"creas"** antes de chequear `num`. No es una **"declaración"**.

Comment: La primera línea de tu función `fibonacci` dice: `int [] fibonacci = new int [num];` Para ese momento no has verificado la validez de `num`. El error que recibes es porque si  `num` es negativo, estás tratando de crear un Array dicéndole que su dimensión ha de ser `num`, y una dimensión de Array no puede ser negativa. Tu programa no llega a entrar en el `if` posterior, porque el error salta en esa primera instrucción: `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -4`, ya que ejecuta: `int [] fibonacci = new int [-4];`.

Comment: Para solucionarlo, basta mover esa primera línea justo debajo de donde termina el primer bloque `if`. Con eso se soluciona ese error que muestras en tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en mis comentarios, el error te salta en la primera línea de tu método `fibonacci`, ya que estás tratando de crear un Array de dimensión negativa, lo cual es algo no válido.

**Código con error:**

```java
public static int [] fibonacci(int num) {
    
    int [] fibonacci = new int [num];  // <- Aquí salta el error
    
    // ...
    
    if(num<0) { // Tu programa nunca llega hasta aquí
        return new int [0];
    }

    // ...
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es muy simple, basta con mover esa linea justo debajo del primer bloque `if`, de tal manera que el Array llamado `fibonacci` se puede crear con una dimensión válida:

```java
public static int [] fibonacci(int num) {
    
    // ...
    
    if(num<0) { // Primero verificamos la validez de num
        return new int [0];
    }

    int [] fibonacci = new int [num];  // <- Ahora si podemos dimensionar el Array

    // ...
}
```

El código completo se puede ver así:

```java
public static int [] fibonacci(int num) {
    
    int num2Anterior=0;
    int numAnterior=1;
    int numeroFinal=0;

    if(num<0) {
        return new int [0];
    }

    int [] fibonacci = new int [num];
    
    if(num>=0) {
        fibonacci[0]=0;
        fibonacci[1]=1;
        for(int i=2;i<num;i++) {
            numeroFinal=num2Anterior+numAnterior;
            num2Anterior=numAnterior;
            numAnterior=numeroFinal;
            fibonacci[i]=numeroFinal;
        }
        
    }
    
    return fibonacci;
}
```